# How can I keep vertical/horizontal scrollbars from flashing on Page load? (Windows)

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website that has custom scrolling, and as such, I would like to hide default scroll bars. I'm using the following CSS to accomplish this:

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This seems to work, but the problem I'm having is that scrollbars flash and then disappear whenever the page loads. This appears to happen in all browsers on Windows. Any idea as to why this might be?

Angular is also being used in the project.

Comment: are you loading the css files at the end of your document or in the head?

Comment: CSS is being loaded in the head.

Comment: it sounds like your content is getting injected before the browser reads the css rules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem:

I had a transition wrapper that Angular was injecting. This transition wrapper had a default `overflow` value, and thus would show scrollbars. Scrollbars flashed because the transition only played for .5s, and then would leave the DOM. Adding the following line to my code made it work:

```
[ui-view].wrapper {
    &.ng-enter,
    &.ng-leave {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```